# pH and aeration of water

Tags: watering

I aerate my water before using them on my plants.  I would like to know if I should go by the pH of the water before or after aeration.

Comment: Are we talking about aquatic plants? Do you have a pond?

Comment: I'd use after. Aeration can leach over saturated carbon dioxide/carbonic acid from the water.

Comment: No to Rob's questions

Comment: The (commercial) hothouse setup I took over for a brief time measured the PH after aeration.